# core.logic stackoverflow when using sets

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

It seems that clojure.core.logic has a problem walking sets.
The minimal failing example:

`(run* [q] (== q #{}))`

produces

> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at clojure.core.logic.Substitutions.walk(logic.clj:344)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_$fn_*2633.invoke(logic.clj:216)
>       at clojure.core.logic$eval2838$fn*_2839.invoke(logic.clj:956)
>       at clojure.core.logic.protocols$eval1389$fn_*1390$G*_1380__1397.invoke(protocols.clj:55)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_.invoke(logic.clj:214)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_$fn_*2633.invoke(logic.clj:218)
>       at clojure.core.logic$eval2838$fn*_2839.invoke(logic.clj:956)
>       at clojure.core.logic.protocols$eval1389$fn_*1390$G*_1380__1397.invoke(protocols.clj:55)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_.invoke(logic.clj:214)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_$fn_*2633.invoke(logic.clj:218)
>       at clojure.core.logic$eval2838$fn*_2839.invoke(logic.clj:956)
>       at clojure.core.logic.protocols$eval1389$fn_*1390$G*_1380__1397.invoke(protocols.clj:55)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_.invoke(logic.clj:214)
>       at clojure.core.logic$walk_STAR_$fn_*2633.invoke(logic.clj:218)
>       at clojure.core.logic$eval2838$fn*_2839.invoke(logic.clj:956)
>       at clojure.core.logic.protocols$eval1389$fn_*1390$G*_1380__1397.invoke(protocols.clj:55)

Why does this generate a Stackoverflow?
unifying with empty vectors/lists/maps/other types works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an answer from the originating author of core.logic that sets aren't supported, but I think you could have phrased your question to be more leading and may have gotten a more interesting response as to *why* sets aren't supported (yet) or what it might take to support them. As to the why, I suspect they are really not needed because `distincto` and `permuteo` provide goals that can be used to test set properties. As to what it might take to support them in unification, follow along below for a rough, ugly, incomplete and inefficient first look.

The stack overflow occurs because sets are collections and collections are recursed into while walking. But since sets are not supported there is no walk implementation for sets and the default for objects is to return itself. The net result is that from the point of view of the walk sets contain themselves and the stack is blown trying to recurse to the bottom.

Join me on the REPL while looking at the [source](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic.clj) and let's hack together something.

```
(use 'clojure.core.logic)
(use 'clojure.core.logic.protocols)
```

Let's tell core.logic to walk sets by using the existing implementation for sequences.

```
(extend-protocol IWalkTerm 
  clojure.lang.IPersistentSet 
  (walk-term [v f] (with-meta (set (walk-term (seq v) f)) (meta v))))

(run* [q] (== q []))
;=> ([])
(run* [q] (== q #{}))
;=> (#{})
```

Good so far...

```
(run* [q] (== q [1 2 3]))
;=> ([1 2 3])
(run* [q] (== q #{1 2 3}))
;=> (#{1 2 3})
```

Consistent, but not terribly useful

```
(run* [q] (== [1 q 3] [1 2 3]))
;=> (2)
(run* [q] (== #{1 q 3} #{1 2 3}))
;=> ()
(run* [q] (== #{1 3 q} #{1 2 3}))
;=> ()
```

Now we have a problem. Both of the last two should return `(2)` since sets have no order, but both return no results. We need to tell core.logic how to unify sets as well. Let's be lazy and try to use the existing `permuteo` to convey the lack of order.

```
(extend-protocol IUnifyTerms 
  clojure.lang.IPersistentSet 
  (unify-terms [u v s] (bind s (permuteo (seq u) (seq v)))))

(run* [q] (== #{1 q 3} #{1 2 3}))
;=> (2)
(run* [q] (== #{3 1 q} #{1 2 3})) 
;=> (2)
```

Excellent!

```
(run* [q] (fresh [a1 a2 a3] (== #{a1 a2 a3} #{1 2 3}) (== q [a1 a2 a3])))
;=> ([1 2 3] [2 1 3] [1 3 2] [3 1 2] [2 3 1] [3 2 1])
```

Very cool.

```
(run* [q] (== #{1 2 [3 q]} #{1 2 [3 4]}))
;=> (4)
```

Nice...but

```
(run* [q] (== #{1 2 #{3 q}} #{1 2 #{3 4}}))
;=> IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :walk of protocol:  #'clojure.core.logic.protocols/ISubstitutions found for class: clojure.core.logic$permuteo$fn...
```

So we were a bit too sloppy using `permuteo`, let's try to kludge it with `clojure.math.combinatorics` instead

```
(use 'clojure.math.combinatorics)

(extend-protocol IUnifyTerms 
  clojure.lang.IPersistentSet 
  (unify-terms [u v s]
    (when (set? v)
      (let [u (seq u)
            v (seq v)]
        (reduce #(mplus % (-inc %2)) 
                (for [p (permutations u)] (unify s p v)))))))
```

And now...

```
(run* [q] (== #{1 2 #{3 q}} #{1 2 #{3 4}}))
;=> 4

(run* [q] (== #{ #{ #{q} :bar} :baz}  #{:baz #{:bar #{:foo} } }))
;=> (:foo)
```

Looks quite promising again.

Comment: I should disclaim that I have only the most basic, rudimentary, crude, and clumsy understanding of core.logic.

Comment: Edited to remove the "exercise for reader"; however, there is plenty of improvement available for the willing. For example, permutations on the entire set generally generates too much work (for the computer that is -- least amount of work for me!). Better would be to first pull out elements in common to both sets.

Answer (score 2):

Sets are not supported in core.logic.